# Network.g file is not generating after flutter upgrade version 2.5.3 or 2.5.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio, flutter-upgrade

We are facing the issue with generating the network.g file after upgrading the flutter version 2.5.3 or 2.5.0. we have used all the latest packages regarding dio, retrofit, retrofit_generator, and build_runner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: initially, our flutter version was 1.5.0, so because of which we did a flutter upgrade to 2.5.3 and as it was not stable we degraded the version to 2.5.0. Now when running the application, it is not generating the network .g file. We have user all the latest packages like dio, retrofit, retrofit_generator, and build_runner, but still the issue remains the same with .g file. So could please help us with which version package should we use to generate the network .g file

Comment: retrofit_generator:retrofit on lib/services/network/api.dart:

Could not format because the source could not be parsed:
╷
19 │ @override Future<CollectionCreatedModel*>* createCollection(auth, body) async  { const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
   │                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
line 235, column 32 of .: Methods must have an explicit list of parameters.
This the error we are getting.